# Google Geocoding API not working with new key?

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm working on a site which uses Google geocoing (geolocation, places) api. I added these api some days ago. It works fine. But then I found now it did not work anymore. Always have exception. After some check, I found this:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

It is because they no longer support keyless access (any request that doesn't include an API key).

So, I follow the instruction, enabled api, create the key, add the key to the call url, waited for about 1 day, but it still does not work. Below is one of the code:

```
public static MapLocation GoogleGeoCode(string address)
{
    MapLocation ret = null;

    try
    {
        var requestUri = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false&key=***", Uri.EscapeDataString(address));

        var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

        var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
        var locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location");
        var lat = locationElement.Element("lat");
        var lng = locationElement.Element("lng");

        ret = new MapLocation
        {
            Lat = double.Parse(lat.Value)
            ,
            Lng = double.Parse(lng.Value)
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        ret = null;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I tried both server key and browser key in my DEV machine. In the browser key, I did not set any referrers. In the server key, I did not fill in anything in option "Accept requests from these server IP addresses".

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong? or, anyone can use the new key to call API?

Thanks

Comment: What exact response do you get? (Please edit it into the question)

Comment: it turns out that it needs https now. once changed to https, it works again with server key.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that it needs https now. once changed to https, it works again with server key.